# PC wont boot from cd/dvd drive

Tags: boot, dvd

I'm having an issue with booting win xp cd drive. I have tried with 2 different drives and different cables, and more bootable cds. Booting process skips part when message "press any key to boot from cd/dvd" should appear, and just boots back to windows.

I tried disable all drives but cd drive in bios boot order, but with same result. Also tried open boot menu with F11 while booting and manual set cd drive as booting option. Optical drives are recognized in BIOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try moving the CDROM over from one SATA controller to another SATA controller. Not just from one port to another port, but to another port connected to a different SATA controller chip. (E.g. my EX58-UD5 motherboard always fails to boot from a CD when I connect it to the Intel SATA ports, but it works if I connect the CDROM to one of the Jmicron SATA controllers.)  Note that this *should* not make a difference. Still, I have at least one example where it *does* make a difference.

Comment: Try disconnecting your hard drive and see if it boots then. If not try the CD in a different machine and see if you can boot then. At least then you will be able to tell if it's a bad disk or not.